# Use GROUP BY without Aggregation to get row data into separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I have a table which looks like this

| Emp_ID | Name | Status | Status_Change_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Active | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | John | Inactive | 01-02-2022 |

I want to write a query to create an output in following format

| Emp_ID | Name | Active Date | Inactive Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 01-01-2022 | 01-02-2022 |

I tried using "case" and "group by" as follows

```
 Select emp_id, 
        name, 
        case when status = active then status_change_date end as "Active Date", 
        case when status = Inactive then status_change_date end as "Inactive Date" 
from empdata 
group by emp_id
```

In this case it shows empty "Inactive Date" column, if I remove group by it just shows distinct rows for each status. Any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Always put strings in quotes, you need to use aggregate function to achieve what you want, `Emp_ID` I took min because.
Try:

```
 Select min(emp_id), 
        name, 
        max(case when status = 'Active' then status_change_date end) as "Active Date", 
        max(case when status = 'Inactive' then status_change_date end) as "Inactive Date" 
from empdata 
group by name
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> min(emp_id)   name    Active Date   Inactive Date
> 1             John      2022-01-01    2022-02-01
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1990fcf7b665b63cf01c004d10f2bd14)